Would compressing the PrCs in the DMG to 3 levels make them competitive with other options?
I came across a discussion recently about the remarkably underwhelming Duelist prestige class that suggested balancing the class by compressing it into three levels instead of ten.  It would put all 1-3 level class features at level 1, all 4-6 class features at level 2, and all 7-10 class features at level 3.  Any level dependent features, like Canny Defense, would reflect this, progressing to 3, 6, and 10 at each level respectively.
This got me thinking about the other classes in the DMG.  With the possible exception of the Horizon Walker, none of the non-casting prestige classes in core remain even remotely competitive for all ten levels.  That brings me to my question: would the above method of level compression, if applied to every DMG prestige class that does not cast spells or advance spell progression, make them into viable options for reasonable builds?  Would any of them be overpowered?
Mostly I'm concerned about whether the Dragon Disciple would be overpowered, since it now has much less opportunity cost for spellcasters, and whether the Duelist and Dwarven Defender would be able to carve out a reasonable niche.  I feel like Shadowdancer and Arcane Archer are very strong, but their prerequisites keep them in line, and that the Horizon Walker is too general-purpose in what it does to pose a real problem.
Here are examples of what the class' level tables would look like after this change:
Arcane Archer



BAB
Fort
Ref
Will
Features




1
2
2
0
Imbue Arrow, Enhance Arrow +2


2
3
3
0
Seeker Arrow, Phase Arrow, Enhance Arrow +3


3
3
3
1
Hail of Arrows, Arrow of Death, Enhance Arrow +5



Dragon Disciple



BAB
Fort
Ref
Will
Features
Bonus Spells




0
2
0
2
Natural Armor Increase (+1), Ability Boost (Str +2), Claws and Bite, Breath Weapon (2d8)
2


1
3
0
3
Blindsense 30ft, Natural Armor Increase (+2), Ability Boost (Str +2, Con +2)
3


2
3
1
3
Ability Boost (Int +2), Wings, Dragon Apotheosis
2



Duelist



BAB
Fort
Ref
Will
Features




1
0
2
0
Canny Defense, Improved Reaction +2, Enhanced Mobility


2
0
3
0
Grace, Precise Strike +1d6, Acrobatic Charge


3
1
3
1
Elaborate Parry, Improved Reaction +4, Deflect Arrows, Precise Strike +2d6



Dwarven Defender



BAB
Fort
Ref
Will
Features
AC Bonus




1
2
0
2
Uncanny Dodge, Defensive Stance 2/day
1


2
3
0
3
Trap Sense +1, Defensive Stance 3/day, Damage Reduction 3/-, Improved Uncanny Dodge
2


3
3
1
3
Mobile Defense, Trap Sense +2, Defensive Stance 5/day, Damage Reduction 6/day
4



Horizon Walker



BAB
Fort
Ref
Will
Features




1
2
0
0
Terrain Mastery x3


2
3
0
0
Terrain Mastery x2, Planar Terrain Mastery


3
3
1
1
Planar Terrain Mastery x4



Shadowdancer



BAB
Fort
Ref
Will
Features




0
0
2
0
Hide in Plain Sight, Evasion, Darkvision, Uncanny Dodge, Shadow Illusion, Summon Shadow


1
0
3
0
Defensive Roll, Improved Uncanny Dodge, Shadow Jump 40ft, Summon Shadow (+2 HD)


2
1
3
1
Slippery Mind, Improved Evasion, Shadow Jump (160 ft), Summon Shadow (+4 HD)




Hierophant is a core non-casting prestige class. Also, your dwarven defender is missing the AC bonus column.

Could have sworn Heirophant advanced spellcasting.  Either way it's not a 10-level class and wouldn't qualify, but I did miss that.  And I'll edit the table.

Rather than looking to make the mechanics competitive, you could instead look to make the idea and the flavour competitive. As in, rather than compressing the levels, give them enough to be worth it as a PrC. Rather than 3 smushed levels of meh class features, I'd love something that evokes a particular fantasy better. Though that's only my preference.

@martixy I actually completely agree.  I've got a rewrite of Duelist that I've been tinkering with on-and-off that I would prefer to use in a real campaign rather than this.  However, this simple trick is a lot easier to implement than a whole new rewritten class, and it would ideally cover several classes at once rather than one at a time.

A way around the volume of classes is to do it on a need-to basis. As you make NPCs or as players express desire. A general way that does not require a custom approach is to allow these classes to be gestalted with others. This would avoid progression issues or breaking base assumptions the game system operates on. For example, instead of compressing to 3 levels, grant 3 gestalt levels across the 10 levels of the PrC. Or a mixed approach - 5 levels + 1 gestalt level. Or whatever you decide the balance point is. Depends on what the goal of the changes is.

Dragon disciple is a big winner, but not for spellcasters
Dragon disciple goes from “you’re shooting yourself in the foot” to “moderately-optimized builds are seriously considering this”—which is ideal if you’re playing in a game with moderately-optimized builds and want dragon disciple to be a viable option for them. On the other hand, if you’re not in a game where a pounce-charger or a hellfire glaivelock is appropriate, dragon disciple may well be too good—pretty much entirely due to its +8 Strength, though the immunities, the flight, the other ability scores, and the bite attack are all quite good as “gravy” goes.
Horizon walker was always decent, and becomes better; it’s probably not problematic, though, since terrain masteries don’t synergize quite as hard as a giant chunk of Strength does.
Shadowdancer is similar: getting hide in plain sight in 1 level was always valuable. Maybe now it’s worth taking the rest of the levels, though none of it is stellar.
Dwarven defender is debatable. There are (much) better options, but at least it’s good for the thing it should be good at (no-selling attacks).
And then there’s arcane archer, which is just a problem, because imbuing arrows with antimagic field is a problem. This change doesn’t really change much: the only reason to be an arcane archer continues to be imbuing antimagic field on arrows, and there’s still no reason to continue taking class levels once you can do that. It’s just 1 level now instead of 2.
Duelist continues to suck. Consider our Q&A on homebrew duelist fixes, we’ve got a bunch.
Finally, one thing to consider is that you can double-dip on a bunch of Dodge and Mobility requirements and take several of these. I haven’t considered what such a build would look like, but the sheer density of class features in these does look like it’d start to add up.
Arcane Archer
The first one up is the biggest problem: arcane archer serves exactly one purpose, and that purpose is a problem. Imbuing arrows with antimagic field is absolutely devastating. Enough that burning three feats and two spellcasting levels may well be worth it—or it would be, if master abjurers (Complete Mage) couldn’t do the same thing more easily and reliably.
Making it so you only need to burn one spellcasting level, obviously, makes that trade easier to take. Still not as easy as master abjurer, but still, if master abjurer isn’t available, this arcane archer looks that much more desirable. But only ever for this one trick, which means there’s really no reason to ever consider the 2nd and 3rd level of the class.
So the question is, do you want a character in your game who has dedicated a lot of resources towards tagging enemies with antimagic field? You probably do not. It makes them a one-trick pony, because the one trick is that good, and the counter-play available is so limited that any time you offer any, it’ll feel cheesy. Maybe this is an improvement, in that they’ve dedicated fewer resources towards this trick, and so it’s not as feel-bad when it doesn’t work. Maybe.
Dragon Disciple
Dragon disciple, without proper spellcasting progression, is and always will be effectively worthless to spellcasters. Nothing it offers provides nearly enough benefit to justify 1-3 lost spellcasting levels. If you want its benefits, it’s far better to just buff yourself than to lose that much spellcasting. You’ll come out ahead.
Thus, dragon disciples are usually melee characters who met the requirement via the most minimal route available, and who all-but-ignore whatever spellcasting they do have.
So what do you get for 3 levels?

Paralysis immunity is nice. At high levels, this becomes worthless because you really need freedom of movement, which covers paralysis anyway, but that’s not reasonable until the teens, while you’ll have this at 8th. Good.

An elemental immunity is also nice. There are a lot of elements and elemental damage tends to be less of a threat for warriors anyway (since much of it is in area-effects that don’t focus them down, and they have relatively-large amounts of hp), so it’s not critical, but you won’t be sorry you have it.

Flight is great! Actually, it’s pretty much mandatory by like 10th, and you’d really rather not wait that long. You could get it by 5th or 6th, for instance. But 8th is pretty good for a warrior type, and it costs little to get. Solid, strong even.

The bite attack is a freebie in a full-attack, so that’s nice. It’s not amazing, and you could easily get one some other way, but as gravy goes it’s solid.

Low-light vision and darkvision are whatever; you might well have those from your race (or if you don’t, you decided fairly-low-power options were worth more). Claws are probably going unused, since you’ll probably want a big weapon, and the breath weapon is almost-certainly going unused, since you won’t get it until 6th level and its damage is already poor then. Natural armor isn’t worth much, though +4 is a decent chunk. By 8th level, when you get the immunity to sleep effects, you’re getting close to achieving that immunity by virtue of your HD alone—deep slumber caps out at 10. Hiss of sleep exists, but if you fail a Will save against a 7th-level mind-affecting compulsion, you should be extremely grateful it only put you to sleep.

+2 to Con, Int, and Cha: Nice, sure, why not. The Con is probably the only one you’ll really use, but no warrior is turning their nose up at another hp/level and a +1 on Fort saves.

And then the elephant in the room: +8 Strength is a lot. I wrote up a big long analysis, comparing with a semi-optimized hellfire warlock (eldritch glaive and Naberius, but no legacy champion cheese), and considering whether or not this dragon disciple is a competitive option for a dungeoncrasher or übercharger. Suffice to say, +8 Strength keeps up—it’s not clearly superior, but it is competitive against—or as part of—fairly-optimized builds. A dungeoncrasher probably goes for it to pick up flight at the same time, even.
On one hand, those builds are not generally considered to be very-high-power in an optimization sense. They can delete opponents they can hit, but magic defenses are so strong that “truly” powerful builds won’t let them.
On the other, this isn’t generally considered a good thing. People generally think of warriors as a reasonable option in Dungeons & Dragons, and in optimized 3.5e, they’re pretty much... not. If you’re playing with fairly-optimal builds, dragon disciple is competitive. If not, it might be too good—but then so are a lot of other things, like pounce multiplying the benefit of charge multipliers, Shock Trooper, Leap Attack, and Battle Leap even existing, and pretty much all spells above 6th level (and also plenty of spells below that threshold).


So yeah, my initial analysis was wrong (I forgot half-dragon was +8; I thought it was half that). This dragon disciple is a competitive option for medium-optimization warrior builds, and that’s not at all trivial. It’s clearly superior to dragon devotee (5 levels to get the weaker draconic template, and generally considered a better option than the 10-level dragon disciple), and it’s good enough that the basic answer of “just be a dragonborn and take better class levels” isn’t a clear win (though dragonborn does cover a lot of the “gravy” on dragon disciple, aside from the +8 Strength).
Duelist
Everything duelist does falls into at least one of the following categories:

Not worth using because its requirements cost more than its benefits:

canny defense, enhanced mobility, grace—no armor or shield
precise strike—one-handed weapon in one hand, nothing in the other
elaborate parry—fighting defensively or total defense


Easily covered by skills or feats:

acrobatic charge—arguably just Jump, maybe Battle Leap or Leap Attack
deflect arrows—...Deflect Arrows
enhanced mobility—Tumble
grace—Lightning Reflexes
improved reaction—Improved Initiative



Canny defense and precise strike are the only things that you can’t trivially get with just a feat, or less, just being good at skills you probably wanted to be good at anyway. Worse, since duelist itself costs two terrible feats (Dodge and Mobility), at best you’re only up one feat, and that assumes you actually wanted Deflect Arrows (which you probably don’t) and Lightning Reflexes (which you definitely don’t, since grace won’t even count as Lightning Reflexes for prereqs).
As for canny defense and precise strike, they’re just an AC bonus and a damage bonus—and both require you to do things that decrease your AC and damage. You can definitely get more AC with armor, and more damage with a two-handed weapon or two weapons, than you can with canny defense or precise strike.
So the only thing that would possibly make sense is if you already wanted to meet those requirements anyway.
For precise strike, there’s basically only one other thing that benefits from the same requirement: Einhander from Player’s Handbook II. It’s bad, though: you get half-as-good elaborate parry, a +2 bonus on Tumble against one target, and sometimes an opportunity to make a free-action feint. You shouldn’t need the Tumble bonus, and anyway it’s really limited. The feint thing is interesting, but it’s impossible to accomplish in the first round of combat, and may not be possible later, either (only works against a target you struck twice the previous round, who may have moved—or, hopefully, died). That’s a problem because feinting is only interesting if you build around it (at least with Drow of the Underdark’s Surprising Riposte, but that’s pricey at 3 feats). You can’t build around something that unreliable. (Einhander might—arguably—have a purpose for a ranged build, but precise strike wouldn’t help with that.) So precise strike is pretty much a dud: the question will always be “can I get more than +7 damage with a two-handed build or two-weapon build?” and the answer will always be “yes.”
Canny defense is doing a little better. Carmendine Monk or Kung-Fu Genius allows a monk to use Intelligence instead of Wisdom; canny defense then doubles your AC bonus from Intelligence (at least assuming your Intelligence is no greater than 30). That’s nice. Four levels and three feats is a lot to ask for, but at least it’s something—with enough Intelligence, and enough other things that use Intelligence, that might look reasonable. Factotum and swashbuckler are obvious options; I guess you could do like monk 1st/factotum 3rd/swashbuckler 3rd/duelist 3rd as a 10th-level build that’s OK-ish but I’m not sure where you go after that. More levels of factotum are going to start really wanting more inspiration, which means a lot of feats on Font of Inspiration and make you question whether three levels and two feats on duelist are worth it. Probably not.
Duskblade probably doesn’t want any part of this. Duskblade has basically no reason not to use armor and a big two-hander, and lots of reasons to avoid wasting levels on non-spellcasting things. Maybe you’d do duskblade 13th/monk 1st/swashbuckler 3rd/duelist 3rd? You miss out on a lot of spells per day that way, but you end up missing out on only spells per day. But you rush duskblade 13th and don’t worry about anything else until after. And duelist is decidedly lower-priority than monk or swashbuckler, sad as that is. Even then, you probably still use a spiked chain, rope dart, or meteor hammer as your weapon, and don’t use precise strike.
Dwarven Defender
In 3 levels, this class is in a weird place. You get a fairly large chunk of AC, enough to be relevant, and when you’re in defensive stance it’s enough to call it a lot of AC. Bonuses like that usually limit your armor or something but this doesn’t; feel free to stack it on full plate or mountain plate or whatever. The DR is really small, but it’s there, and uncanny dodge certainly doesn’t suck. (Trap sense does suck, but whatever.) Are those worth 3 class levels? Probably not really, but one does have to admit you really will be tough to hit. The problem is that it doesn’t do anything else for you: no offense, no non-AC defenses. The small Strength bonus on defensive stance and the fact that the class has good Fort and Will saves aren’t really enough here. (The resistance bonus on defensive stance doesn’t even count, since you should definitely have a cloak of resistance that’s as good or better by the time you qualify.)
So 3 levels make you good, or even really good, against attacks, but do nothing else, and you need 3 terrible feats to get in. Is that a fair trade? No, not really: you’re going to need those feats to buy some kind of offense or utility. Plus you probably want some feats for doubling down on some of your benefits, maybe Deflective Armor (Races of Stone) to make your touch AC absurd, but that’s another two feats. So you’re probably going to burn more levels on getting bonus feats, which is rough. Pugilist fighter (Dragon vol. 310) is a start, since that can get you Endurance and either Dodge or Toughness (and Improved Unarmed Strike, should you want it).
And then there’s the elephant in the room: defensive stance is terrible. It’s rage, except with a decent AC bonus instead of a minor AC penalty, and you can’t move. That makes it nearly useless: moving is just so absolutely crucial. Worse, you can’t even just try to use it and if you have to give it up, so be it: you get penalized for that, making you worse off. It’s a fairly-large difference in AC, but I’d rather just have rage.
There are arguably ways to cheese around the movement restriction on defensive stance (allies moving you rather than you moving yourself is the big one), but I’m discounting those as irrelevant: if the class only makes sense if you cheese around its big thing, then it doesn’t make sense. (Also, off the top of my head, none of the ways around it seem worthwhile.)
In theory, defensive stance also has the hypothetically-large benefit of not restricting your patience or concentration—but there’s basically no way to leverage that as a dwarven defender. A dwarven defender spellcaster is kind of an interesting idea, but only kind of, and the cost for doing it is immense, and with that BAB requirement, you’re only doing it at pretty high levels.
Finally, it’s worth noting that the deepstone sentinel prestige class, from Tome of Battle, 1. already exists, and 2. is five levels long. It’s also... OK! Ish. I mean, Stone Dragon requires you to stay grounded, which is awful, and deepstone sentinel introduces something that require you not to move more than 5 feet, but

It’s far less crucial to the class, it’s got plenty of other stuff going on,
There are no extra penalties for losing it, you just lose the benefits, and
It’s not limited per-day, if you have to move you can just do that and then spend a swift action re-assuming mountain fortress stance.

Deepstone sentinel is a vastly better incarnation of this concept than even a 3-level dwarven defender.
Horizon Walker
Horizon walker was always a decent-ish class, at least in a restricted-source environment. Search for “horizon tripper” to see it in action.
Anyway, this makes the most important facets of horizon walker happen in 2 levels instead of 6: nice! That’ll keep it more competitive in a wider-source environment.
Shadowdancer
Shadowdancer 1st for hide in plain sight was always worthy of consideration and it remains so here; there aren’t a lot of options for getting it in 1 level (note: Tome of Magic’s dark creature template probably doesn’t actually do what you want). The cost, in terms of the prerequisites, is fairly painful—between the 10-rank requirement pushing back when you can enter, and the requirement for Dodge and Mobility, there’s a lot of reason not to bother. But at least now there’s more reason to consider continuing the class.
I honestly have no idea how good the rest of the class features are; I’ve never played with them, discussed them, or spoken with anyone who has. Evasion, uncanny dodge, and the improved versions of each are nice. Slippery mind is decent, too. Less impressed with shadow illusion or shadow jump; those are good effects, but very limited numbers. At least you’re getting them faster here.
The big question is summon shadow. Shadows are nasty, but again, risk being a one-trick pony. Stuff that works on shadows is going to get rid of them in a hurry, even with the extra HD. (Thank goodness for the protection against turn, rebuke, and command!) And that comes with an XP time bomb, so that sucks. I guess if nothing else they make phenomenal spies, which is probably what most shadowdancers want to use them for anyway.
In exchange for 2 feats and 2d6 sneak attack damage, shadowdancer is probably worthwhile. In exchange for everything one might do with 2 feats and 3 levels, maybe less so, but it’s not painfully bad. I’d probably still prefer assassin unless I really want hide in plain sight ASAP, though.

On your note about Canny Defense, the Duelist would be treated as higher level.  Any level dependent ability would be treated as class level 3 at 1, level 6 at 2, and level 10 at 3 - which would be full Int-to-AC at level 2 in most cases.  Not sure how much that tips things - would it make it a useful class for Carmandine Monk or possibly Factotum or Duskblade?

@PhoenixDuck Missed that (it also would have confirmed for me the AC bonus on the dwarven defender), fair enough. Uh... Carmendine monk, factotum, and swashbuckler, maybe, but I can’t see a duskblade wanting to give up armor, a better weapon, and spellcasting progression for what duelist offers. For that matter, a factotum would want to take Font of Inspiration to make up for it, which becomes another cost to an already-costly thing. I’ll consider and revise.

This is overpowered compared to the base classes.
Balancing 3.5 material against all other options is a tricky, because there's a big difference between balance as written, and character optimization.
As written, the DMG 3.5 PrCs are mostly from 3.0-era content (i.e. weaker balance) with not much changed to update them to the higher standard of 3.5 works. However, reducing them to three-level PrCs is to triple the potency of each level, which swings too much in the direction of overpowered. In the context of character optimization builds, this could potentially open up new avenues to make an optimized character even more powerful.
Dragon Disciple
The Dragon Disciple is relatively easy for a non-spellcaster to qualify for: any class can gain Knowledge (arcana) as a class skill by a feat (per this question and gain arcane spellcasting by a level dip in Sorcerer. In three levels of this, he essentially gains Half-Dragon without losing hit dice or save progression.
It doesn't solve the age-old problem of Dragon Disciple being useless for primary spellcasters, since three full levels of spellcasting progression is too much. Sorcerers are already down a level in 3.5 when it comes to gaining a new spell level, so being four caster levels and two spell levels behind is a severe drawback. (Incidentally, 5e solves this by doing away with the concept of non-full casting; arcane casters can specialize, but not in a way that they lose 20/20 spellcasting.)
Addendum
KRyan has challenged me to demonstrate that Dragon Disciple is in fact overpowered as a three-level class. While I cannot speak to optimized builds on character optimization forums, which are certainly more powerful than D&D's base classes and beyond my expertise, the three-level Dragon Disciple is massively more powerful than the base classes, primarily because it grants Strength +8 at no loss of base attack or hit dice.
Compare a straight Barbarian 8 to Duskblade 1, Barbarian 4, Dragon Disciple 3 (taking a feat to make Knowledge (arcana) a class skill for his Barbarian levels). Most of what our draconic friend loses is more than compensated for by other abilities:

He loses a point of base attack and a daily use of Rage, but he has Strength +8 permanently, which gives +4 attack and +6 damage.
One of his hit dice is d8 instead of d12 for an average -2 HP, but Con +2 gives him +
He loses Improved Uncanny Dodge, a point of Trap Sense, and DR 1/–, but his Armor Class is +4 higher and hit points +1/level higher.
His saves are actually  better due to the Con bonus, multiclassing, and good Will save.

He also has flight, blindsense, bite attack, darkvision, an elemental immunity, breath weapon (perhaps occasionally useful at lower levels), a few other things, and at least nine 1st-level duskblade spells per day when you aren't raging.
For an analysis comparing to the standard of balance on character optimization forums, I lack the relevant expertise. I suspect the best option is to ask on character optimization forums. Cynically, you might also ask at a D&D Wiki, who have a very generous understanding of balance.

I feel it’s worth mentioning that barbarian 8th is a really poor comparison; barbarian 3rd through 10th are very close to being dead levels. I think the case is a lot less one-sided for a duskblade 8th; we are not talking about some fine-tuned optimized build, just something beyond a core melee class. But—that said—you’re absolutely right, +8 Strength is enormous. Thank you for this answer and challenging me on that, dragon disciple is far better than I gave it credit for (I missed that jump from +4 to +8).
